# How to install galaxy role with a different name than in git url?

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

There is a galaxy role: git@site.net/ansible-myapp.git

I can install it like this:

```
ansible-galaxy install git+git@site.net/ansible-myapp.git
```

, but it creates a role with the name "ansible-myapp".

How can I install a role with a different name than in git url?

It's possible to do via requirements.yml:

```
- src: git@site.net/ansible-myapp.git
  scm: git
  name: myapp
```

`ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml` will install it with the name "myapp"

But how to do it in one command without requirements.yml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this actually undocumented feature (at least I did not find the doc) with trial and error, extrapolating from the [official doc](https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/using/installing.html)

Add the desired name after the version.

```
ansible-galaxy role install git+git@site.net/ansible-myapp.git,master,myapp
```

This will install the role as `myapp` using the specified version. For `master` version, if this is the default repository branch, you can pass an empty version which will default to it:

```
ansible-galaxy role install git+git@site.net/ansible-myapp.git,,myapp
```

This was tested with:

```
$ ansible-galaxy --version
ansible-galaxy 2.9.10
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/user/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-galaxy
  python version = 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) [GCC 8.4.0]
```

NOTE: The TYPE positional argument `role` in the above command line was introduced to differentiate roles and collections, and will default to `role` if omitted (for compatibility with previous ansible galaxy versions)